# ListView add items two times in onCreate

Tags: android, android-listview

In my MasterDetail Flow I call this function to create my list:

```
public class Ansicht extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //...
        ListItems.setupMainItems(this);
        //...
    }
}

public class ListItems 
{
    public static List<DetailListItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DetailListItem>();
    public static Map<String, DetailListItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DetailListItem>();

    public static void addItem(String value, Typ t) 
    {
        DetailListItem item = new DetailListItem(value, t);

        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    //...
}

public class ListControl extends SherlockListFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListItems.DetailListItem>(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.simple_listitem, android.R.id.text1,ListItems.ITEMS);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //...
}
```

But if I close my app and start it again the items are insert a second time. I think I do not have to call this function in onCreate but this [image](http://blog.cloverink.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/activity_lifecycle.png) does not really help me because onCreate is the first method with is called.

In my `setupMainItems` method I only call the addItem method. The `onPause` and `onResume` are never overriden. If I close my app with the homebutton all works great but if I close it with the back button the items are insert a second time.

Comment: Make sure you didn't call setupMainItems again. and share the code of setupMainItems

Comment: Also, paste here what's inside the `OnPause()` and `OnResume()` methods if you have overriden them. The source of `setupMainItems` will for sure be of use, as mentioned by @Pankaj Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
if(ListItems.ITEMS == null || ListItems.ITEMS.size() == 0)
    ListItems.setupMainItems(this);
```

That way it'll only add the items if they haven't been added already